# matlab regexprep: replace multiple instances but stop after first replace

Tags: regex, matlab

How do I achieve from this: `regexprep('asdf',{'a','aa'},{'aa','bb'})` the output `aasdf`? I want to run regexprep, but stop after the first match. The parameter `'once'` had no effect. The output with the line above is `bbsdf`

Comment: [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58502294/11089932) of course is a workaround here, but in general, this is intended behavior, see the [`regexprep`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) doc: _`regexprep` applies the first expression to `str`, and then applies each subsequent expression to the preceding result._ The `once` option only applies to the first occurence of a match, e.g. test `regexprep('asdfa',{'a','aa'},{'aa','bb'},'once')` to see the different functioning.

Comment: @HansHirse I understand it's intended and I already wrote I tested the `once` parameter, it didn't work... the question is, how can I achieve this, by means of using regular expressions?

Answer (score 1):

You could try doing the replacements in the opposite order, e.g.

```
regexprep('asdf',{'aa','bb'},{'a','aa'})
```

In this case, the `aa` replacement would fail, because `aa` does not occur in the original input string.

Comment: hm. I need to adapt the example, this workaround does not work for me